# Google Sheets App Script - Alert Not Executing In Order

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a "file walkthough" for my Google Sheet to help users get a feel for how to use it. I'm currently activating ranges, then throwing an alert to show the user some context about that range. However, the lines are not executing in order.

I've tried breaking out the alerts and selections into separate functions, using Utilities.sleep(5000), and highlighting using setBackground() instead of activate, but everything has the same result. Even if I have only one activate and one alert it seems to trigger out of order

```
function setup_file_walkthrough(){
        var budgetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Budget');
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

        budgetSheet.activate();
        ui.alert('This is the budget tab ...');

        budgetSheet.getRange('F:F').activate();
        ui.alert('This is a column...');
}
```

I'm expecting the sheet/range to be selected, then a pop up message to appear. User clicks OK then it moves on to select the next range, and another message appears, etc.

However, everything I've tried results in the same thing: all of the messages pop up one after another without any change in the sheet, then it goes straight to the last .activate. Almost as if I wrote it like this (in fact, these 2 code snippets are giving me the same result):

```
function setup_file_walkthrough(){
        var budgetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Budget');
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

        ui.alert('This is the budget tab ...');
        ui.alert('This is a column...');
        budgetSheet.getRange('F:F').activate();
}
```

Comment: Try using [SpreadsheetApp.flush](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

Comment: See also the explicit method [`SpreadsheetApp#setActiveSheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#setactivesheetsheet-restoreselection) which may have better sense wrt being flushed before other UI code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function walkThru() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
    var msg=Utilities.formatString('This is sheet %s.', shts[i].getName());
    shts[i].getRange("A1").activate();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(msg);
  }
}
```